# Error con Else if &&

Tags: php

Tengo un problema del que no se porque falla.

Son estos dos statements, he revisado durante rato y buscado soluciones y no doy con la solución.

Yo los veo correctos, si algúien puede darme alguna pista del fallo le agradezco el favor.

La intención en este es que si `$field` tiene el valor `seguro` y el resto no són `avila`, `lago`, `casals` o `tiemblo`:

```
}else if (($field == "seguro") 
           && ($address != "avila" 
           || $address != "lago" 
           || $address != "casals" 
           || $address != "tiemblo"))
{

}else if (($field == "seguro") && ($address == "casals")){
```

En ambos casos me están fallando y no sé donde está el fallo.

Dejo abajo el código completo.

```html
try {
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
 $ticket_date_from = $_POST['ticket_date_from'];
 $ticket_date_to = $_POST['ticket_date_to'];
 $quantity_from = $_POST['quantity_from'];
 $quantity_to = $_POST['quantity_to'];
 $field = $_POST['field'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
 
   if ($field == "seguro") {
    $field_db = "type_insurance";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE $field_db LIKE '$busqueda'";
    //$query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE type='seguro'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    //$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
   
   }else if (($field == "seguro") && ($address != "avila" || $address != "lago" || $address != "casals" || $address != "tiemblo")){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE type='seguro'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
   }else if (($field == "seguro") && ($address == "casals")){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE type='seguro' and type_address='Calle Pau Casals'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
      
   }elseif ($field == "de"){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE $field LIKE '$busqueda'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    //$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

   
   }elseif ($field  == "tax"){
     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE $field='1'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    //$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

   } elseif ($field == "renta"){
     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE $field='1'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    //$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
     
    
   }elseif ($field == "fecha"){
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE ticket_date BETWEEN '$ticket_date_from' and '$ticket_date_to'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    //$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

   }elseif ($field == "cantidad"){
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM recibos WHERE quantity BETWEEN '$quantity_from' and '$quantity_to'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    //$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

   }
  }else{
    $query  = "select * from recibos";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    //$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
 echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: comenta tu error asi podriamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: ¿Qué fallo da? Y, por favor, explica mejor la lógica porque no entiendo que en el primer `if` tengas esto: `if ($field == "seguro") {` y en el siguiente tengas esto: `}else if (($field == "seguro") && ($address != "avila" || ...` Eso no tiene sentido, porque cuando sea igual a `seguro` entrará en el primer `if`, ¿qué sentido tiene ese segundo `if` si nunca entrará en él realmente? Explica con sencillez cuáles son las condiciones que deben cumplirse porque hay cosas incongruentes en el código.

Comment: ¿Por qué no te ayudas con el `in_array` con un array `$respuestas`?

Comment: Disculpar es cierto que no he puesto que error da. La sentencia elseif contiene un query de mysql, dichas queries no aparecen, pero no da un mensaje de error.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias, el primer if entra bien. El problema son los otros dos siguientes.

TIenes razón que no tiene mucho sentido.

FernandoTorres no tengo mucha idea de php. Si me pones un ejemplo a lo mejor de como se hace puedo implementarlo en el código y hacerlo más sencillo.

Muchas gracias a todos.